# export folder of PSDs and JPGs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

Ive got a folder full of PS files that I want to export as JPGs.

So far, I open each Photoshop file and use *File → export* on each file manually. Is there a quicker way where I can tell Photoshop to open all PSD files in the folder and export them as a new folder full of JPGs?

(I’m running Creative Cloud latest (as of Sept 17) on OSX 10.10.)

Comment: Bridge can do this in a breeze with a ton of options.

Answer (score 6):

You would just need to use the Image Processor that comes preinstalled with CC.

Select your starting folder, then the output folder and whatever settings you want.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a folder for your JPGs.
2. Go back into Photoshop, open the *Actions* panel and create a new action.
3. Open up one of the PSD files and go through the motions of saving it as a JPG into that JPG folder you just created earlier.
4. After saving it, close your file (do not save) and *Stop the Action.*
5. Now that you have that action saved, you can go into *Batch* which is located here: File → Automate → Batch.

[image: Batch Dialog box]

This method is good if you intend to do this often.